# Typescript scope augmentation Object

Tags: typescript

I want to extend the Object methods creating "isEmpty".

```js
// typings/object.d.ts

declare global {
    interface Object {
        isEmpty(): boolean;
    }
}

Object.prototype.isEmpty = function (this: Object) {
    for (let key in this) {
        if (this.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
};
```

and then I'd like to use it in my source code with:

```js
let myEmptyDict = {};
let myFullDict = {"key": "value"};

console.log(myEmptyDict.isEmpty()); // true
console.log(myFullDict.isEmpty()); // false
```

It looks like isEmpty is not defined, how can I solve it?
I'm Using Typescript 3.6.2.

Comment: I'd recommend not monkey-patching in production; even though its possible to "type" in typescript

Answer (score 0):

What you have is correct, with a slight addition. This [GitHub issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/17736) and this [Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47736563/2690790) have a few more details.

```js
export {}; // ensure this is a module

declare global {
  interface Object {
    isEmpty(): boolean;
  }
}

Object.prototype.isEmpty = function(this: Object) {
  for (let key in this) {
    if (this.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
      return false;
    }
  }

  return true;
};

let myEmptyDict = {};
let myFullDict = { key: "value" };

console.log(myEmptyDict.isEmpty()); // true
console.log(myFullDict.isEmpty()); // false
```

[TypeScript Playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAbwL4G44Hp12AOwM4CuUwcMAFgJZ5xVwCGcAthACYEA2wAUFy8AMbs6xOAHN2EAEZ12iLnBo4YwKADM6-EgHlJAKwHwE8hTTwBRRmBgBPABQBKAFxxJECJzo4UxpF19cdfX4YADowKAgYSOswYBCqCytrOABeOFUCHGCKCBxbcipnQIN7OQVVaDhbTngAa2BkihxSSjxSoxMaVSqCvBCyOjwtAHccAAUI2Ng7eut7duNO4hgiZvV2PGBvTt8FfwVl1dIoAi2-by4apmtEmwARCmDUxFRL4HhGawAxDnYHp7SCDgs2cACIAG4yU6guCvLj8XJ4dxxCSiWyfW7Wf6hBKWGwOexoTDHU7wxHIkKo9HfX7Y+LmPF2eZErDrTZcIA)

Comment: Same, I get: `Uncaught TypeError: myEmptyDict.isEmpty is not a function`. Note: I put this in a typings folder and then used in a component.

Comment: Note: The referenced Typescript Playground doesn't work due to "Executed JavaScript Failed: Unexpected token 'export' ". To fix, navigate to TSConfig -> Module and change to `CommonJS`. Not sure if you can update the Playground accordingly @skovy?