# How to automatically load files that contain specific decorators in a node project

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, decorator, typescript-decorator

I have created a decorator, in **Project A** (the main library) and would like to have all of those decorators automatically loaded when the app starts in **Project B** (the project using Project A). Is there anyway of doing this?

**index.ts** looks like this:

```
export function MyDecorator<T extends Controller>() {
  return (target: new () => T) => {
    // Do stuff with the decorator
  }
}

const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {

})
server.listen(8080)
```

Is there something that I can do to automatically execute `@MyDecorator()` on all classes in **Project B** without **Project B** having to do so?

**MyClass1.ts**

```
import { MyDecorator } from 'project-a'

@MyDecorator()
export class ProjectBClass1 {}
```

**MyClass2.ts**

```
import { MyDecorator } from 'project-a'

@MyDecorator()
export class ProjectBClass2 {}
```

Comment: I'm not sure you can do this, node had `global` but I'm not sure either it could help. Do you had any example in one of opensource library out there? I only know NestJS and it had the decorator exported.

Comment: I have never used NestJS, but looking at the docs it might be what I want, but I am not sure. In the docs it doesn't look like they ever reference their controllers, they just create them and they are there, which is what I am kinda looking for.

Comment: No, you still need to Import its decorators in NestJS, I mean if you had any opensource example I would love to dig in. I only use TS in NestJS and Angular, and they always export it. I don't see any global implementation on this.

Comment: @mandaputtra Importing the decorators is fine, I just don't want to have to import `MyClass1.ts` or `MyClass2.ts`, I would like them to be auto imported.

Comment: @GetOffMyLawn -- did you find a nice solution for this?

Comment: @Jonathan no, I never did find a solution to this.

Answer (score 1):

- I assume you mean creating instances by load .
- Also I'm not sure if that is an elegant solution but here is my suggestion:

Create a class that has a static method:

```
class ControllerCreator {
  private static constrollerInstances: any = []
  private static controllerConstructors : any = [];  

  static registerControllerClass(ctor: any) {
    ControllerCreator.controllerConstructors.push(ctor);
  }

  static createInstances() {
    ControllerCreator.controllerConstructors.forEach(
      ctor => constrollerInstances.push(new ctor()) // pushing them to static array to not lose
    )
  }
}
```

In your decorator you should register your controller constructor:

```
export function MyDecorator<T extends Controller>() {
  return (target: new () => T) => {
    // Do stuff with the decorator
    class newClass extends target {
      // ...
    }

    ControllerCreator.registerControllerClass(newClass);
  }
}
```

And finally at some point you should call:

```
ControllerCreator.createInstances();
```

Comment: No, I do not want to create instances. I want to execute my decorators without having to do a `import {...} from '...'` within my code. I just want them to automatically import or automatically bootstrap the files.

Comment: Do you just want to get rid of import statements? If so is that helpful for you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47736473/how-to-define-global-function-in-typescript

Comment: In **Project B** yes. In **Project A** I would like to not load the files, but I could just glob them and do an import there if need be, but would really like to not have to.