# Define global function in module

Tags: typescript

I can define a global function in a non-module file:

foo.ts:

```
function foo() {}
```

I can call that function from a file bar.ts without importing foo.ts:

bar.ts:

```
foo(); // call global function foo
```

However, as soon as I import another module into foo.ts, foo.ts is turned into a module and the global definition disappears. Resulting in an error in bar.ts when trying to call foo.

How can I define a global function in a module that is global across the entire project without importing it.

EDIT:

I know about the `declare global` syntax, but in that case I would need to write every function signature twice: Once to declare it globally and once to bind it to `globalThis`. I am looking for something with less boilerplate.

Comment: Would [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47736473/how-to-define-global-function-in-typescript) help?

Comment: I saw that “declare global” trick, but you have to write the signature twice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like `declare global` is really required in such a case. The only (verbose) solution I found is:

```
declare global {
  function foo(): void;
}

globalThis.foo = () => {};
```